# Is there a way to access a .NET MVC ViewBag's properties using a string key?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewbag

I have a value that I've put in the ViewBag:

```
ViewBag.SomeKey = value;
```

In my view I have the key stored as a String.

```
String theKey = "SomeKey";
```

Is there a way to access my value from the Viewbag using this String version of the key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ViewData[theKey]`. Both `ViewData` and `ViewBag` use the same underlying storage.